# Default Perl accessor for objects

Tags: perl, oop, accessor

If I have a Perl class eg

```
package Foo;

sub new {
    my ($class,$hashref) = @_;
    my $self = bless $hashref, $class;
}
```

and initialised with

```
my $foo = Foo->new( { bar => 2, othervar => 8 } );
```

I can do

```
print $foo->{ bar };
```

which feels clunky, and

```
print $foo->bar
```

feels more preferable. However, if there are a lot of keys, I'd prefer not to have to write an accessor for every key (or is that best practice) ?

So, I can include

```
our $AUTOLOAD;
sub AUTOLOAD {
    my $self = shift;

    my $called =  $AUTOLOAD =~ s/.*:://r;

    die "No such attribute: $called"
        unless exists $self->{$called};

    return $self->{$called};
}

sub DESTROY { } # see below
```

In perldoc perlobj it says
`# XXX - this is a terrible way to implement accessors`

Are there any good ways to implement accessors like this, without using other packages, eg Moose, Class::Accessor ? I'm just after something light as its just one class that has a lot of keys.

Comment: Perl doesn't have this built in. The autoload variant is indeed not great. Class::Accessor is one option. There's Moose and Moo if you don't need the MOP. There is also Mo and Class::Tiny. I explored various different object implementations recently when I built https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::LocalAttribute, so the docs for that have more alternatives.

Comment: After using Class::Accessor I think this fits my requirements actually. It does method checking, so errors if theres a typo, and doesn't need a cpan module, so if you want to set this as an answer, more than happy to accept.

Comment: Class::Accessor is not in core, so you do need "a cpan module". But why is that bad? You probably have it installed already.

Comment: Ah maybe something else has already pulled that in anyway. I was trying to avoid needing to update servers, but tbh thats fine.

Comment: Take a look at https://metacpan.org/pod/Util::H2O

Comment: Re "*this is a terrible way to implement accessors*", Because of the inefficiencies of running the AUTOLOAD sub each time. Generating the subs is the way to go.

Comment: I tend to think that if you have some many properties in your object, your object might be too big. I don't know if that's true for you, but it's something I consider when I design things.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I have been considering this, and think it's more during initial phases when you don't necessary know at first how the structure will look, but still want an attempt at doing the right thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there any good ways to implement accessors like this, without using other packages ...

If you insist, then write those subs directly to the package symbol table

```
package AutoAccessors;

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @attr_names;

BEGIN {
    @attr_names = qw(name mode etc);
    no strict 'refs';
    foreach my $accessor (@attr_names) {
        *{$accessor} = sub { do {
            if    (@_ == 1) { $_[0]->{$accessor} }
            elsif (@_ == 2) { $_[0]->{$accessor} = $_[1] }
            #elsif ...
        } };
    }
};


sub new {
    my ($class, $args) = @_;
    my $self;
    foreach my $attribute (@attr_names) {
        # Check, initialize, set from $args, etc 
        $self->{$attribute} = $args->{$attribute} if $args->{$attribute};
    }   
    return bless $self, $class;
}   

1;
```

Then

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use AutoAccessors;

my $obj = AutoAccessors->new({ mode => '007' }); 

$obj->name('Bond');
say "name's ", $obj->name;
say "mode:  ", $obj->mode;
```

This is done in a number of CPAN packages (and it's usually more elaborate).

Having said that, I see no good reason to avoid good libraries, far more carefully written and tested and complete. For instance, [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo) as a full system comes in at around 5 kloc (if I recall correctly) and has barely a handful of dependencies, while [Class::Accessor](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Accessor) is just over [200 loc](https://metacpan.org/dist/Class-Accessor/source/lib/Class/Accessor.pm) with one dependency that I can see.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's very helpful and I've learnt something. I've settled on Class::Accessor for the time, but I may implement this as well to understand better.

Comment: @Ian "_I've settled on Class::Accessor_" -- Glad to hear that, I think it's better to use libraries here.  While this and related topics are very good to know about one normally doesn't need it (nor want it if there are good "canned" alternatives)